# Clarification and Intuition about Measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions

So, I've been assigned the following question:

Consider a mapping $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Are these statements true or false?

$(a)$ If $f(x, ·)$ is Borel measurable for every $x$, and $f(·, y)$ is continuous for every $y$, then $f$ is Borel measurable.

$(b)$ If $f(x, ·)$ is Lebesgue measurable for every $x$, and $f(·, y)$ is continuous for every $y$, then $f$ is Lebesgue measurable.

I'm really not sure how to interpret the measurable parts. I have a hard time visualizing what's going on. For the continuous parts, it's just for a fixed $y$, $f(x,y)$ varies continuously in $x$. But I'm not sure how to reconcile the definition of Borel measurable functions I know with this (preimage of open sets is Borel). So I guess what I'm asking for is clarification/intuition, and not the answers.

Thanks!

Comment: Using the given assumptions, try to construct a sequence of measurable functions $f_n$ with $f_n (x,y) \to f(x,y)$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: For (a), for every $x$, define a function $g_x : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $g_x(y) = f (x, y)$. Then the preimage $g_x^{-1}(A)$ of a Borel set $A$ is a Borel set. While continuity tells you something about how the image behaves ($x$ sufficiently close $y$ implies $h(x)$ close to $h(y)$ for continuous $h$), measurability is concerned with the preimage. So if you have some structure on the domain, for example a measure, you do not "lose" this structure after transformation by a measurable function. Does that help?

Comment: The sequence of functions idea ended up being the way to go. Thank you both!